# How can mp3tag be used to generate playlists with the naming scheme of Exact Audio Copy?

Tags: exact-audio-copy

I'm using Exact Audio Copy V1.1 and mp3tag V2.71 on Windows 8.1.

I like the character replacement approach of EAC for filenames. For each of the characters `"\/:*?<>|`, a replacement character can be defined.

I'm postprocessing tags with mp3tag due to sorting requirements. In accordance with the changed tags, filenames change. Thereofre, the playlist also needs to be updated.

How can I make mp3tag write a playlist where the filename matches the EAC convention?

Comment: Please note the tooltip text when you place your mouse over the download button of a question. It reads "This question does not show any research effort; it is unclear or not useful." It does not read "I don't like the author."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

mp3tag can generate a playlist, even in UTF-8 format. The name of the playlist can be configured (`options` -> `playlist`).

You can use the [mp3tag Scripting Functions](http://help.mp3tag.de/main_scripting.html) to map characters of the playlist's file name. However, you cannot denote the domain characters in question directly, because some nasty test checks for their occurence without considering the presence of Scripting Functions. You can work around this using e.g. `$char()`.

An incomplete example for a playlist file name config setting :

`$replace(%artist% - %album%,$char(34),'''',$char(92),-).m3u8`

Comment: Please note the tooltip text when you place your mouse over the download button of an answer. It reads "This answer is not useful." It does not read "I don't like the author."